# Is it possible to save Cloud Anchor to local storage for using it later?

Tags: anchor, augmented-reality, arcore

I am making an AR application. The requirement is simple. In the 'configuration phase', I start the app and put a cube on the floor of a room, then close it. Later when I start the app again, when facing the camera toward the same floor, the cube should stay there. Based on the information I found, it is NOT possible without Cloud Anchor. In my case I don't really need to share the anchor among different users or different devices, I just need to 'persistent' the anchor.

Is it possible to somehow serialize/save to local storage and load it in later session?

Please help to confirm, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In ARCore 1.20 and later, Cloud Anchors can be resolved for **365 DAYS** after they are hosted. In versions of ARCore earlier than 1.20, Cloud Anchors could be resolved only for **24 HOURS** after they were hosted.

In versions ARCore 1.12 ... ARCore 1.19, you can't access **`Cloud Anchors`** in **twenty four hours** of using them. Although it's potentially possible to use your own hosting service for **Shared Anchors**, but in that case you'll be unable to use an ARCore Cloud Anchor API (because **Cloud Anchors** do require access to the Google cloud).

I haven't still been found a code for Shared Persist `ArAnchors` (anchors that can be saved in one session and retrieved in another session for multiple devices). For creating your own localization code for anchors you need to properly set a 6DOF `ArCamera` and `ArAnchors`' position and orientation (a.k.a. `Pose`) in ARCore scene.

Comment: Thanks! I know the fact that ARCore Cloud Anchor can last for only 24 hours. For using my own hosting service for cloud anchors, firstly thing that I need to do is to save/serialize it. My question is 'is it possible to save/serialize it?' and how.

Comment: Guys I'm keen to know if that's sorted out. I need to retrieved the old anchors from the potential last session... Any updates on this topic?

Comment: Hi @FernandoPrieto, Alas! At the moment there's still no updates on this topic...